# Javascript/Discord.JS sistema de probabilidades de varias funciones

Tags: javascript, nodejs, discord.js

resumidamente me estoy volviendo loco buscando esto, estoy hace 1 año haciendo un bot para discord y estoy reformándolo todo porque ya con este tiempo aprendí un poco mas y puedo mejorar mi código. Entre las cosas que tengo que mejorar, tengo que mejorar un sistema de probabilidades que tenia para algunos objetos o funciones, la idea seria la siguiente, tengo supongamos 3 funciones, una que se llama espada, una moneda y una diamante, con la acción de registrar un nombre en una base de datos y mostrar un mensaje embed diciendo ejemplo obtuviste la espada, el sistema otorga probabilidades a los objetos haciendo que no sea igual de posible que te salga en el ejemplo anterior una moneda que un diamante (teniendo en el sistema la moneda mas posibilidad de salir y el diamante menos al ser mejor) que sistema se les ocurre que me podría servir, el sistema que estaba usando actualmente es el siguiente:

> function probabilidad() {

```
var n100 = Math.random()*511+1;

var n3;

if(n100<=3) { //3
  n3 = sc();
} else if(n100<=3.1) { //0.1
  n3 = spf();
} else if(n100<=30){ //26.9
  n3 = hp();
}
```

Es muy primitivo y funciona hasta ahí, porque quería cambiar algunas probabilidades de algunos objetos pero como podrán ver si le cambio un numero a un if cambiarían todos los de abajo, necesito un sistema en el que yo asigne un numero de probabilidad a un objeto y teniendo en cuenta su probabilidad sea ejecutado.

Comment: Hola, no termino de entender qué es lo que necesitas. Podrías detallar un poco más formalmente el resultado que esperas obtener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te propongo una alternativa para hacer el código más reutilizable y ser más fácil añadir premios, guardas los objetos y sus probabilidades en un objeto de js, es el objeto probabilities (no tienen porque estar en orden ascendente, funciona igual).

Cualquier modificación de una parte de la probabilidad afecta siempre al resto, pero dado que quieres poder modificar las probabilidades libremente la mejor forma es que si tocas una afecte de igual forma a las probabilidades del resto, no como con if else que solo afecta a algunas y no a otras.

En este caso la probabilidad de un número es su probabilidad divido la probabilidad total de todos los objetos, siendo lo más fácil que entre todos sumen 100 pero pueden sumar la que sea. En este caso el diamante tiene 1/91 de salir.

Lo mejor es que modificando el objeto puedes modificar la probabilidad y añadir nuevos objetos.

```
function sc() {
    console.log("diamante");
}    
function spf() {
    console.log("espada");
}    
function hp() {
    console.log("moneda");
}    

function probabilidad () {
    const probabilities = {
        diamante: {
            p: 1,
            fn: sc
        },
        espada: {
            p: 30,
            fn: spf
        },
        moneda: {
            p: 60,
            fn: hp
        },
    }
    let totalProb = 0;
    
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(probabilities)) {
        totalProb += value.p;
    }
    
    const luckyNumber = Math.random() * totalProb;        
    
    let totalValue = 0;
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(probabilities)) {
        if (luckyNumber < (value.p + totalValue)) {
             return value.fn();
        } 
        totalValue += value.p;
    }
}
probabilidad();
```

Comment: Loco la verdad, sos un genio, termine haciendo un codigo gigante con 3 millones de cosas que funcionaba mejor que el anterior mio pero esto la verdad, increible un trabajo impecable, Muchisimas gracias.